# Comparing items in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, compare

Let's say I have an array of objects:

```
 var array = [ 
   { id: 1, pt: 0 },
   { id: 2, pt: 12 },
   { id: 3, pt: 7 },
   { id: 4, pt: 45 },
   { id: 5, pt: 123 },
 ];
```

I want to iterate through the array (using something like `array.forEach` or `array.map` and compare the `pt` attribute in each item to those of the other items in the array. My objective is, for each item, find the 3 other items that are closest in value to that items `pt` value. For example. for `id: 1` the closest items in value are 2,3, and 4. For `id: 3` it would be 1, 2, and 4, etc... How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Edit in the outcome you want to see from your example. Really helps visually.

Comment: How many items are there? (Roughly)

Comment: sort by `pt` then look ahead and behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You yould map the result of a filtering to exclude the pivot element and sort by absolute delta and take the wanted amount as result.

```js
function closest(n, { id, pt }) {
    return array
        .filter(o => o.id !== id)
        .sort((a, b) => Math.abs(a.pt - pt) - Math.abs(b.pt - pt))
        .slice(0, n);
}

var array = [{ id: 1, pt: 0 }, { id: 2, pt: 12 }, { id: 3, pt: 7 }, { id: 4, pt: 45 }, { id: 5, pt: 123 }],
    result = array.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, { closest: closest(3, o) }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

At first lets sort the array:

```
array.sort((a, b) => a.pt - b.pt);
```

Now the closest elements are somewhere directly before or after the element.  To get them one might just go forward and backward:

```
function getClosest(pos, n) {
  let lower = pos - 1, upper = pos + 1;
  const distance = i => Math.abs(array[pos].pt - array[i].pt);
  const result = [];
  while(result.length < n) {
    if(lower >= 0 && distance(lower) < distance(upper)) {
       result.push(array[lower--]);
    } else if(upper < array.length) {
       result.push(array[upper++]);
    } else break;
  }
 return result;
}
```

To now get the 5 closest ancestors of the first element:

```
getClosest(0, 5)
```

Comment: [Try it out!](http://jsbin.com/cevaqupuna/edit?console)